# Utility to simply show status of Ctrl, Shift, Alt keys?

Tags: windows, keyboard, status, modifier-keys

Where could I find a small Windows utility to show the current status of the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> keys?  Something that lives in the system tray or otherwise "always on top"?  Just little "lights" to say *"Ctrl is pressed!"*

Comment: THIS looks so good, unfortunately only in Linux :) http://code.google.com/p/key-mon/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Done:

http://svn.lando.us/joey/Public/SO/SU114626

Used the [low-level keyboard hook code by Stephen Taub](http://blogs.msdn.com/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx). May contain bugs, malfunctions and other weird things. May eat babies without prior warning. Right-click to close.

[image: Works on my machine]

Feel free to use or adapt the code as you see fit.

Comment: @Chris: Well, not the prettiest one and sorta hacked together but at least it works :)

I thought about a notification icon but I wasn't able to cram the strings »Ctrl«, »Alt« and »Shift« into a 16×16 px² image and three notification icons were a little too much, I thought. Anyway, should be trivial to adapt if the need arises :)

Comment: Rössel: Hey, it fits the bill just fine.  Thank you thank you!

Comment: Done. I should probably put this on Github, I guess.

Answer (score 4):

While waiting for Joey to fix his link, I made another one. Download the executable (and code) here: https://github.com/BobVul/KeyStatus/releases

It uses basically the same method as Joey's, and supports the Windows key. The display is <s>a little</s> much bigger.

[image: Screenshot]

Do whatever you want, no warranty, yadda yadda yadda

Comment: Link broken - any news on where it's gone?

Comment: @ReversedEngineer Oops, you might be the first to notice since GitHub got rid of the downloads section! Updated with a fresh build, but this is rather old code so I'm not sure how reliable it will be into the future.

Comment: Thank you, @Bob, got it and it seems to work just fine on Windows 10 22H2

Comment: This is very well made, good UI for the task! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

[Windows on-screen keyboard](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/10762/windows-use-on-screen-keyboard) fits your *"always on top"* and *"small Windows utility"* criteria. Each time <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> or a modifier key is pressed it'll be highlighted on the on-screen keyboard. It's built-in so you don't need a 3rd party app.

[image: osk]